# Pre-compile razor views in asp .net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, razor

I have an ASP .Net MVC5 website, I have performance issues, I want to pre-compile the razor views and exclude them when deploying my website in IIS, I followed the steps indicated in [this article](http://stacktoheap.com/blog/2013/01/19/precompiling-razor-views-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-3/) but I got an error : RazorGenerator.targets was not found, in fact I checked in the package folder I din't find this file.
Do you have any idea why this dll not found in the package folder ? The [RazorGenerator.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc) and [RazorGenerator.MsBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild) are installed correctly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use static html files?

Comment: My views are not static, I retrieve some data from db

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need RazorGenerator for this. When publishing just set the option to "Precompile during publishing", under "File Publish Options" on the "Settings" tab. Click "Configure" and then tick "Merge all outputs to a single assembly". Give it a unique name, generally something like `[ProjectName].Precompiled`.

Comment: Can you please explain me where can i find this settings, I'm using webdeploy?

Comment: It's in the publish dialog. There's a Settings tab at the left, and then under where you choose the configuration you want to deploy is a down arrow button labeled "File Publish Options".

Comment: ok thank you for your answer, I got the following error :  It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' 
beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: I have just deleted the obj folder, the error  gone now, I get another one, it says that the namespace log4net could not be found , it uninstall it then I reinstall it but the error persist

Comment: Is there any way to compile views during normal builds instead of a publish?

Comment: https://blog.rsuter.com/precompile-asp-net-mvc-razor-views-in-release-mode-to-find-errors-at-compile-time/ @NineTails this should help

Comment: I also have a question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715367/how-can-i-get-precompiled-razor-files-when-deploying-net-web-application that relates to this answer as well. Making sure that the checkbox "Allow precompiled site to be updateable" is unchecked to have precompiled views.