# Deploy ASP.NET Application while Hiding Sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

When we deploy our ASP.NET MVC application all sources, controllers, views, etc. are copied.

This is not a problem when we deploy on our server, but when we are going to deploy a copy into external servers and we don't want to share our code.

Does not exist a tool to package into libraries? .NET Core seems to deploy into DLL files, but I don't find that functionality on ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Use the Publish feature in Visual Studio. Everything that's compile-able will be compiled. You can set your views to be pre-compiled too as an extra. Obvious things like Javascript cannot be compiled but that's the same for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

> Does not exist a tool to package into libraries?

**Yes.**

This is what [publishing the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components) does - it prepares the application for deployment. When you publish, it will compile the source code and prepare only the assets your application needs to run into a deployment folder.

It compiles the source into libraries. Views are only compiled if you use the [precompile views option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674473/pre-compile-razor-views-in-asp-net-mvc-5), otherwise they are distributed as files.

> Use the Publish tool to deploy to a local folder. The exact options available depend on your app type. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project and choose Publish, and then choose Folder. For more information, see [Deploy to a local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-local-folder).
>
> [image]

Tutorial: [Publish your Hello World application with Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio)

You can combine publishing with [IIS Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) in order to easily automate the process of deploying your web site.