# Web application using Razor slow rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a big performance problem in my website when I deploy new code. 
I have many views in my website. After deploying new version of code, the first call to my main page take 5 minutes (vs 2 seconds in normal time). When i use a web analyzer like `dynatrace` i see that i have an application lock. For example : I have this schema :
[image]
When i look to the stack details, i saw that i have a lock on these methods :

1. `ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult`
2. `BuildManager.CompileWebFile`
3. `ViewResult.FindView`
4. `RazorView.RenderView`

Is that a problem with my views compilation ?

Thank you for your help and your advices.

Comment: Try pre-compiling your Views.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675482/11605410

Comment: Pre-compiling views resolved my problem. Thank you